# Algorithm for image of a free group homomorphism

Tags: gr.group-theory, free-groups

Let $G$ and $H$ be finitely generated free groups, and let $f:G\to H$ be a homomorphism specified by giving the images of the generators of $G$.

Is there an algorithm which takes such an $f$ and a word $w\in H$ and tells if $w \in f(G)$?

Is there such an algorithm in the special case where $G=H$?

Thanks-

Comment: See http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/fga/doc/manual.pdf section 2.3 for a GAP implementation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are asking whether an element in a free group lies in the span of a set of elements (the images of the generators). This is the *generalized word problem* which is known to be decidable for free groups (for an algorithm, see, for example: Stallings' "Topology of finite graphs" (Inventiones, 1983), though the result is several decades older.

Comment: Actually, he is asking for the uniform generalized word problem since he wants f as part if the input.

Comment: Stallings algorithm does solve the uniform generalized word problem.